# How to rename all files in a folder

Tags: bash, scripts

I have a folder that contains many files named with the same structure:

```
file.number1.2010.720p.otherinfo.mp4
file.number2.1990.720p.otherinfo.mp4
....
```

I would like to remove all the sequence:

```
YEAR.720p.otherinfo
```

So name will be:

```
file.number1.mp4
file.number2.mp4
....
```

And finally I would like to remove all dots (.) except the one at the end (.mp4)

What commands should I use to create such script ?

Comment: Useful commands are grep, sed, and awk. What have you tried, and did it work, or fail? Have you searched for answers, with a search such as https://www.google.com/search?q=mass+rename+linux ? BTW, Linux 14.04 has reached end-of-life https://ubuntu.com/about/release-cycle and we are limited to provide support to current versions https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic , such as 16.04 LTS, 18.04 LTS, 19.04, and alternate flavors https://ubuntu.com/download/flavours

Comment: "What commands should I use to create such script ?" script?! we got a "rename" command for that ;-) Have a look at `man rename` and `man rename.ul`.

Comment: I use Krusader file manager with krename . menu is file-multirename . you can prefilter using menu view-custom before that .

Answer (score 6):

This will do the job:

**Firstly:** Install `rename` by running the following command in the terminal:

```
sudo apt install rename
```

**Secondly:** In the terminal,`cd` to the directory containing your files.

**Finally:** Rename the files to your desired format by running the following command in the terminal:

```
rename 's/^(.+)\.(.+)\.(.+)\.(.+)\.(.+)\.mp4$/$1$2.mp4/' *
```

**Done**

---

**Notice:**

To see how the `rename` command will operate on your files but without really renaming them ( just print the output to the terminal ), you can add the option `-n` after it. Like so:

```
rename -n 's/^(.+)\.(.+)\.(.+)\.(.+)\.(.+)\.mp4$/$1$2.mp4/' *
```

---

**Explanation - as requested by [Hamza](https://askubuntu.com/users/923705/hamza):**

**Part # 1:**

```
's/ORIGINAL/NEW/'
```

Substitutes the `ORIGINAL` string with the `NEW` string.

To see how it works as simple as it gets:

- Please run in the terminal `rename -n 's/file.number1.2010.720p.otherinfo.mp4/NEW.mp4/' *`
- Assuming you have a file named `file.number1.2010.720p.otherinfo.mp4` in the current directory.
- The output would be `rename(file.number1.2010.720p.otherinfo.mp4, NEW.mp4)`

**Part # 2:**

```
^(.+)\.(.+)\.(.+)\.(.+)\.(.+)\.mp4$
```

Starts at the beginning of the string `^` and then matches one or more character/s ( any character ) `(.+)` before the dot `\.`

This group is put into a variable `$1` and repeated four more times ( five in total ) each group is put into a variable ( `$2`, `$3`, `$4`, `$5` ) until `.mp4` represented as `\.mp4` is reached.

Makes sure the string ends with `.mp4` by using the `$` symbol which matches the end of the string.

This part is, however, a bit flexible and will give you undesired results if the file naming is inconsistent and you have files with more than five parts separated by dots in their names like `file.number1.2010.720p.otherinfo.extrainfo.mp4`

If this is the case, please substitute this part with the more strict regular expression below. This way it will only operate on files with five parts separated by dots in their names only:

```
^([^.]+)\.([^.]+)\.([^.]+)\.([^.]+)\.([^.]+)\.mp4$
```

**Part # 3:**

```
$1$2.mp4
```

Defines the new file name as what is under the variable for the first group `$1` ( in this case `file` ) + what is under the variable for the second group `$2` ( in this case `number(x)` ) + `.mp4`

**Part # 4:**

```
*
```

Operates on all the files in the current directory.

Comment: Please, what's the meaning of 's/^(.+)\.(.+)\.(.+)\.(.+)\.(.+)\.mp4$/$1$2.mp4/' * ?

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`cut`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/cut) and [`bash` string manipulation](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/073):

First approach: only with `cut`:

```
for I in .*mp4
do
    echo mv "$I" "$(echo $I | cut -d. -f 1,2,6)"
done
```

Explanation:

- `for...` will select all `.mp4` files
- `echo $I |` will convert the `I` variable into an input for the next program
- `cut -d. -f 1,2,6` will select fields 1, 2 and 6 where fields are separated by `.`

But this approach can be problematic since, the 6th field may be not the extension.

---

So you can have a second way:

```
for I in .*mp4
do
    echo mv "$I" "$(echo $I | cut -d. -f 1,2).mp4"
done
```

With that command, you force the extension to be `.mp4`. It will work, but what if you have not only `mp4` files with the same naming pattern?

---

In that case, you can use extension selection:

```
for I in *mp4 *avi
do
    echo mv "$I" "$(echo $I | cut -d. -f 1,2).${I##*.}"
done
```

- `${I##*.}` will allow you to select what is behind the last `.` in variable `I`

---

Note: to prevent bad behavior, I added `echo` in the commands to see what they will do before running them really.

Answer (score 1):

Select all files and press F2; then do what's shown in the image below. 
[image: bulk rename]

https://docs.xfce.org/xfce/thunar/4.12/bulk-renamer/start

Comment: This, however, is applicable for Xubuntu only, with Thunar and the Bulk Rename plugin installed.

Comment: works in ubuntu (er gnome idk) too now with nothing installed

Comment: it works well if you have all files in the same directory but won't change files in included directories

Answer (score 0):

I always use Thunar (filemanager) for this
just open it, select the files you want
to alter (cut/paste/adjust/replace characters)
and then rightclick->rename

you get a sophisticated menu with lots of
options and ways to change your file names 
and their extensions, and see their previews 
in the right panel.